# Отложенные сообщения Telegram bot Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем здравствуйте. Делаю бота для Telegram на Node.js и node-telegram-bot-api. После команды /start бот проверяет наличие юзера в базе, если его нет, то нужно отправить 6 сообщений с определенным интервалом. И вот тут проблема. Если указывать интервал между сообщениями 1-2 минуты, то все ок, но если установить интервал 15-30+ мин, то сообщения не приходят. Складывается ощущение, что Node просто перестает работать не дожидаясь завершения таймаутов. Пробовал и setInterval и setTimeout - результат одинаковый. Подскажите, что не так. Весь код как есть прикладываю ниже.

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api')
const TOKEN = 'API_TOKEN'
const Koa = require('koa')
const Rout = require('koa-router')
const bodyParser = require('koa-bodyparser')
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')



const bot = new TelegramBot(TOKEN)
bot.setWebHook('https://site.com/API_TOKEN')

const app = new Koa()
const router = Rout()

router.post('/API_TOKEN', ctx => {
    const {body} = ctx.request
    bot.processUpdate(body)
    ctx.status = 200
})
app.use(bodyParser())
app.use(router.routes())
const port = 3000
app.listen(port)

var notes = []

const KB = {
    refering: 'Реферальная программа',
    getRefLink: 'Получить реферальную ссылку'
}


const msgs = {
     referMsg: 'тут сообщение'
}

var userName = ''
var firstName = ''
var lastName = ''
var userId = ''

var block1 = `Сообщение 1`
var block2 = `Сообщение 2`
var block3_1 = `Сообщение 3`
var block3_2 = `Сообщение 4`
var block4 = `Сообщение 5`
var block5 = `Сообщение 6`

var isFollower = 0

bot.onText(/\/start/, msg => {

    userName = msg.from.username
    firstName = msg.from.first_name
    lastName = msg.from.last_name
    userId = msg.from.id;

     notes.push({
         'uid': userId,
         'text': block1,
         'text2': block2,
         'text3_1': block3_1,
         'text3_2': block3_2,
         'text4': block4,
         'text5': block5
     });

     var referId = '0'
     var startText = msg.text
     if(startText.length > 7){
         referId = startText.substr(7);

         if(referId.length > 0){
             referId = referId
         } else {
             referId = 0
         }
     }

request('https://site.com/api?getuser='+userId+'&username='+userName+'&first_name='+firstName+'&last_name='+lastName+'&refer='+referId, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error)

    if(response.statusCode === 200){
        const apiData = JSON.parse(body)

        const html = `<b>User:</b> - <em>${apiData.id}</em>`
        if(apiData.id != 0){
            isFollower = 1
        }
    }
})


const text = `Приветственное сообщение`

bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, text, {
                reply_markup: {
                    keyboard: [
                        [KB.refering]
                    ]
                }
            })
})

bot.on('message', msg => {
     switch (msg.text) {
         case KB.refering:
              sendRefProgramm(msg.chat.id)
         break
         case KB.getRefLink:
             sendRefLink(msg.chat.id, msg.from.id)
         break
    }
})

function sendRefProgramm(chatId){
    request('http://site.com/public/api?get_user_refs='+chatId, (error, response, body) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error)

    if(response.statusCode === 200){
        const apiData = JSON.parse(body)

        var referals = apiData.referals
        var referalInfo = ''
        if(referals > 6) {
            referalInfo = `На данный момент ты привел ${apiData.referals} человек. Получить бонус можно написав мне @username`    
        } else {
            referalInfo = `На данный момент ты привел ${apiData.referals} человек.` 
        }

        const referalInfoMsg = `Сообщение`+referalInfo
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, referalInfoMsg, {
            reply_markup: {
                    keyboard: [
                        [KB.getRefLink]
                    ]
                }
        })
    }
})
}

function sendRefLink(chatId, userId){
     var msg = 'Ваша реферальная ссылка https://t.me/bot?start=' + userId
     bot.sendMessage(chatId, msg)
}

if(isFollower == 0){
// Block1
setTimeout(function(){

        for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
            bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], notes[i]['text'], {
                reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                    inline_keyboard: [
                        [{ text: 'Регистрация', url: 'https://site.com' }]
                    ]
                })
            })
            bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], 'Учавствуй в реферальной программе, приглашай друзей и получай бонусы!', {
                reply_markup: {
                    keyboard: [
                        [KB.refering]
                    ]
                }
            })
        }

    // Block 2
    setTimeout(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
                bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], notes[i]['text2'], {
                    reply_markup: {
                        keyboard: [
                            [KB.refering]
                        ]
                    }
                })
            }

        // Block 3
        setTimeout(function(){
            for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
                bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], notes[i]['text3_1'])
                bot.sendPhoto(notes[i]['uid'], 'img.jpg')
            }
            // Block 3_2
            setTimeout(function(){
                for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
                    bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], notes[i]['text3_2'])
                    bot.sendPhoto(notes[i]['uid'], 'img.jpg')
                }
                // Block 4
                setTimeout(function(){
                    for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
                        bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], notes[i]['text4'], {
                                        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
                                            inline_keyboard: [
                                                [{ text: 'Регистрация', url: 'http://site.com' }]
                                            ]
                                        })
                                    })
                    }
                    // Block 5
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++){
                            bot.sendMessage(notes[i]['uid'], notes[i]['text5'], {
                                            reply_markup: {
                                                keyboard: [
                                                    [KB.refering]
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        })
                            bot.sendVideo(notes[i]['uid'], 'video.mp4')
                            notes.splice(i,1);
                        }
                    },3573000)
                },1797000)
            },30000)
        },1800000)
    },540000)
},60000)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
function sendTime(time, msg, text) {
        new schedule.scheduleJob({ start: new Date(Date.now() + Number(time) * 1000 * 60), end: new Date(new Date(Date.now() + Number(time) * 1000 * 60 + 1000)), rule: '*/1 * * * * *' }, function () {
            bot.sendMessage(msg.chat.id, text);
        });
    }
```

Отправить сообщение с текстом "текст" с ожиданием 5 минут при получении /send:

```
bot.onText(/\/send/, msg => {
     sendTime(5,msg,'текст')
})
```